# Не работает обработчик события после загрузки ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, html5

Подргужаю 2 кнопки Ajax запросом. Вешаю обработчик на див елемент.Когда кликаю по 1 кнопке события работает,когда делаю клик по 2 кнопке ничего не происходит.В чем проблема?

```js
$('.Portfolio').on('click', '.clickOne',function(e){
console.log(e);
//Работает
});
$('.Portfolio').on('click', '.clickTwo',function(e){
console.log(e);
//НЕ Работает
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="Portfolio">
<button class="clickOne">Click 1</button>
<button class="clickTwo">Click 2</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Если смотреть ваш сниппет, то всё там работает...

Comment: Работает так как кнопки я тут не подгружал ajax запросом , а просто написал их в html

Comment: дак какая именно часть тут подгружается аяксом? кнопки, или див целиком? ну или убедитесь что селекторы указаны корректно